# Why not use string buffers instead of immutable strings?

Tags: string, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

More and more compilers make use of immutable strings (because of string interning, but are there other reasons?). However, string buffers are much faster when concatenating strings. Is there any reason why not all compilers use string buffers internally instead of immutable strings?

Comment: Decision to made immutable object has goal to good control (if T is 13, never be 14), is pro good quality developed code. Move elegance of the language higher. Few places need better performance, so Stringbuilders etc. BTW immutability has positive impact for speed too: aggresive compilers, thigh thread safe etc.

Comment: In other words: immutability was invented not because of absence others way, but like conscious project in area OOP

Answer (score 1):

Probably the biggest argument for immutability is its benefits for concurrency. There's no need to lock and protect an object if you know it will never change. As the cores in our multi-core processors multiply, this benefit becomes more and more compelling.

There are trade-offs, of course. As you mention, string buffers can out-perform the constant allocation of new strings in apps that do a lot of string manipulation. Luckily, most languages include a string buffer tucked away in a library. By default, immutable strings are safer. In some cases, they're faster. If you find they're not working for you, you can always swap in a buffer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Do you know any benchmarks that test immutable strings vs string buffers, and immutable strings win? Or could you maybe give any hints on how such a benchmark would be constructed?

Comment: Considering space: Immutable strings may use less space if strings are repeated over and over. Every buffer will contain a copy, while (depending on the implementation) there's only one interned immutable string. Time: Immutability means you can cache results from string operations. It's safe because the source won't change. Imagine searching within a string and caching the result. I'm not saying it's common, but it can be done. Also, heavy multi-threading may need more time with buffers (coordinating access). As with all benchmarks, you can find a scenario where buffers perform better.

Comment: My problem is that I can't find a benchmark where buffers do _not_ perform better. I'll keep looking.